# using subprocess Popen with multiple quoted arguments

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to use Python's subprocess to execute a couple of commands in gdb non-interactively.

The equivalent command I'd execute in the shell would be:

```
gdb - 9833 -ex "set someval=50" -ex "p someval" --batch
```

I want the following output:

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
[New Thread 0x2b6c64f09dc0 (LWP 9833)]
[New Thread 0x549ec940 (LWP 12128)]
[New Thread 0x585f2940 (LWP 12127)]
: ...
0x0000003670407655 in pthread_join () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
$1 = 50
```

When I try to script it in Python to get the same output, the gdb arguments don't get executed. I'm using cmdline args to fill in the command string.

I see gdb attaching to the pid when I print the output but I don't see the gdb print output, and neither is the set performed.

Here's my script:

```
cmd = ['gdb','-',pid,'-ex','"set ' + sys.argv[2] + '=' + sys.argv[3] + '"','-ex','"p ' + sys.argv[2] + '"','--batch']
print cmd
result = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
print result
```

---

Thank you, @larsks. Your response really cleared up my muddled understanding of the cmd format. Unfortunately I'm stuck with Python 2.4 in my environment, so I can't use the more elegant str format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got too many quotes.  If you have a shell command that looks like this:

```
echo "this is a test"
```

The equivalent call to subprocess.Popen is:

```
subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'this is a test'])
```

That's a command of two elements, and just like in the shell command the second argument contains whitespace.

With that in mind, this:

```
gdb - 9833 -ex "set someval=50" -ex "p someval" --batch
```

Becomes something like this:

```
cmd = ['gdb','-',pid,
       '-ex','set ' + sys.argv[2] + '=' + sys.argv[3],
       '-ex','p ' + sys.argv[2],
       '--batch']
```

Although I think this is a slightly more clear way of getting to the same place:

```
cmd = ['gdb','-',pid,
       '-ex', 'set {}={}'.format(sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3]),
       '-ex', 'p {}'.format(sys.argv[2]),
       '--batch']
```